# Is it possible to take a backup and upload to Azure without accessing the host machine?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I encountered a roadblock while attempting to make a backup.

I am working from my workstation, running PowerShell scripts from my work station.

```
$server = "THESERVER"
$db = "THEDB"
$datetime = (Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy-hh-mm-ss-tt');
$database1 = 'C:\temp\' + $db + '_' + $datetime + '.back';
$creds = Get-Credential 'admin'
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $server -Database $db -BackupFile $database1 -Credential $creds;
```

this reports an error:

```
Backup-SqlDatabase : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Cannot open backup device
'C:\temp\THEDB_07-20-2021-04-14-06-PM.back'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
At C:\Users\alilland\Documents\dev\bin\sql-server\db_backup.ps1:7 char:1
+ Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $server -Database $db -BackupFile  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Backup-SqlDatabase], SmoException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailed,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.BackupSqlDatabaseCommand
```

this error is taking place because my filepath is a *local* filepath to my machine, not a filepath that exists on the host of the sql-server, which fully makes sense, I completely understand why that error is taking place.

While looking at the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-full-database-backup-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#b-full-backup-to-azure) I came across the following PowerShell script for backing up a SqlDatabase and uploading to azure. It appears that I can pass in an azure container from my workstation, where I wouldnt need to be logged in to the host machine in order to make it work.

```
$credential = Get-Credential
$container = 'https://<myStorageAccount>blob.core.windows.net/<myContainer>'
$fileName = '<myDatabase>.bak'
$server = '<myServer>'
$database = '<myDatabase>'
$backupFile = $container + '/' + $fileName
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -BackupFile $backupFile -Credential $credential
```

before I go through the hassle of setting up an azure container with permissions, I know I can get the script to successfully run on the host, but will Backup-SqlDatabase accept an azure container path and upload to azure from *my workstation* without installing any CLI tools on the host machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will Backup-SqlDatabase accept an azure container path and upload to azure from my workstation without installing any CLI tools on the host machine?

Yes.

This is a built-in SQL Server feature called [Backup to URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url?view=sql-server-ver15), as wrapped in [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/backup-sqldatabase?view=sqlserver-ps#example-11--backup-a-database-to-the-azure-blob-storage-service).  So either PowerShell or TSQL should work.

Answer (score 0):

> will Backup-SqlDatabase accept an azure container path and upload to azure from my workstation without installing any CLI tools on the host machine?

What exactly are you asking?

- **Will it work from your workstation?** Yes, it will work by executing it from your workstation.
- **Is the upload happening on your workstation?** No, it won't upload it from your workstation. The server will upload it.